# Why does blender mix colors when exporting FBX?

Tags: texturing, export, .fbx

Quick question, I have a .blend file with a high poly mesh that has multiple materials on it. When I export as FBX some textures get mixed up, example picture shows original .blend file on the left, middle is FBX export number one, and after adding one plane to the roof, it's a completely new mixup of textures on the right. All textures are simple Principled BSDF colors.

[image]

Comment: Bugs should be reported at https://developer.blender.org. You will have to provide them a minimal example file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this, as I copy and pasted items each one of them had all of the other material information. So then I ended up (and I don't know how this is posible) with multiple materials under the SAME NAME.

So the solution was to go and manually go to edit mode, select each color to see if its information is on the mesh and then reassign it or remove it, I had over 40 materials on this mesh and was left with 9, problem solved but I wish I found some elegant solution to this.